# Can't get Lumina camera to go away

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I'm trying to develop an iOS app that has camera functionality using the Lumina framework. The majority of the app is built using SwiftUI, but I understand that Lumina was built to work with UIKit. I have set up a button that shows the camera, but I cant' get the cancel button to dismiss the camera.

I am using two Swift files to control the camera, Measure.swift and ViewController.swift, which I have copied out below.

```
//Measure.swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import Lumina

struct Measure: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isCameraVisible: Bool
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let vc = ViewController()
        return vc
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        uiViewController.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            return Coordinator(isCameraVisible: $isCameraVisible)
    }


    class Coordinator: NSObject, LuminaDelegate {
        @Binding var isCameraVisible: Bool

        init(isCameraVisible: Binding<Bool>) {
                _isCameraVisible = isCameraVisible
        }

        func videoRecordingCaptured(_ videoURL: URL?, error: Error?) {
            isCameraVisible = false
        }

        func dismissed(controller: ViewController) {
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            isCameraVisible = false
        }
     
    }

    
    

    
}
struct MeasureWrapper: View {

    @State private var isCameraVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            if isCameraVisible {
                Measure(isCameraVisible: $isCameraVisible)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
            }
            else {
                Button(action: {
                        isCameraVisible.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Show camera")
                }                    
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Measure_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MeasureWrapper()
    }
}
```

```
//ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Lumina
  

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: LuminaDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let camera = LuminaViewController()
        camera.delegate = self 
        camera.setShutterButton(visible: false)
        camera.setTorchButton(visible: false)
        present(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension ViewController: LuminaDelegate {
    func dismissed(controller: ViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```